# Where else I can find ngx-bootstrap other than github

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am not able to access github at my workplace. But i need to get ngx-bootstrap file for my development.
Please suggest any other location.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and usually should, get it using *npm* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap).

If you have *node* and *npm* installed on your computer:

1. Open a terminal
2. *cd* into your project
3. Run this command: `npm install --save ngx-bootstrap`

Comment: this command will try to download the bootstrap from github only. Which will give me an error.